# Richfaces:  a4j:commandLink with both onclick and actionListener

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.1.0.Final.
I have a problem similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106223/jsf-using-onclick-actionlistener-together), however the remedy (return true;) does not work for me.
It may be the version of Richfaces I'm using, but upgrading is very difficult for me and I'd like to verify that's the problem first or preferably find a workaround.

I have an a4j:commandLink link in a rich:column in a rich:dataTable in a rich:tab within a rich:tabPanel.  I'd like to click the link, have the column data saved to the backing bean (e.g. via f:setPropertyActionListener) and then have the user switched to another tab for editing (using: #{rich:component('TabPanel')}.switchToItem('EditTab');)

If I use oncomplete for the javascript piece, the handler fires, but the switchToItem piece doesn't work.  If I instead use onclick for the javascript piece, the handler doesn't fire, but the switchToItem piece does work.  I need both.

Does anyone know of a solution?  Is this a known problem in this version of Richfaces?  Does anyone know how I can work around this problem using other components?

I apologize in advance, but I cannot post my code.

Thanks,
John

**Update:**

I upgraded to Richfaces 4.2.2.Final, but there was no improvement.  Apparently it is impossible to use a4j:commandLink with a f:setPropertyActiopnListener if you also use the oncomplete to switchToItem another tab.

Comment: just try it with rich faces 3.3, coz I'd similar problem with 4.1.0 final and it worked fine with 3.3.3

Comment: I'm afraid downgrading isn't an option.  But thanks for adding fuel to the Richfaces bug theory.

Comment: How exactly does `switchToItem` in `oncomplete` fail? Does it fail as in "It never switches", or as in "It switches, but it still shows the old content".

Comment: Hi BalusC.  Using onclick, it switches to the other tab, but the setPropertyActionListener never fires.  If I use oncomplete, the listener fires, but I have to switch to the other tab manually.  If I add "alert('here');" ahead of the switchToItem code on the oncomplete, I don't even get the alert.

Comment: ...(oops)... I do get the alert, but the switchToItem doesn't work.

Comment: If it matters, the switchType of the rich:tabPanel is ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I added a second f:setPropertyActionListener to set the TabPanel's activeItem to EditTab.  Then I added oncomplete="location.reload(true);" to refresh everything and redraw with the correct active tab.

It works, but I'd still like to hear a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with RichFaces 4.2.2.Final and it worked for me when I used onclick:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{model.simple}" var="item">
    <rich:column>
        <a4j:commandButton value="click me" onclick="#{rich:component('tabPanel')}.switchToItem('tab3');" action="#{bean.action}">
            <a4j:param assignTo="#{bean.parameter}" name="param" value="#{item}"/>
        </a4j:commandButton>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>

<rich:tabPanel id="tabPanel">
    <rich:tab name="tab1">tab 1 content</rich:tab>
    <rich:tab name="tab2">tab 2 content</rich:tab>
    <rich:tab name="tab3">tab 3 content</rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

Regards,
Palo